# How to install software from Arch boot disk to existing Arch system?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

I've got an existing Arch Linux installation. After booting from the installation media, is there some way to install software either from the installation media or using the network I've set up using the installation media (that is, without setting up networking again after an `arch-chroot`)? The use case is that my installation with the base system doesn't seem to have the `wireless_tools` package installed which seems to be necessary to get a wireless connection. Since setting up a wired connection is infeasible at the moment, it would be great to use the boot disk for this.

Comment: There is no `iwtools` package; do you mean `wireless_tools`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the network persists even when you `arch-chroot`. But if you still want the answer, just use `pacman --root /wherever/your/install/is/mounted`.

See also `man pacstrap`.

Comment: There's no `pacstrap` manual on the installation medium, but `pacstrap -h` gives some limited information. The system is already "`pacstrap`ped".

Comment: ah, OK. I think you can also use `pacstrap`, which is why I mentioned it, but you might have to be careful about it copying the keyring on the live CD, and also maybe the package cache location it uses (I forget the exact details).